# How do i use Excel to manage part of my risk management project?

Tags: google-sheets, business-intelligence, business-process-management

Using two cells in an excel document (likelihood and severity) which are coloured accordingly, can excel use those two cells to create a risk score in another cell (with red - 3, Amber - 2, Green - 1)? Essentially putting a score in a new cell? I hope this makes sense. I'm probably making it sound more confusing than is needed.

I have used Stackoverflow to try and find something similar but to no avail as yet, have tried some CF but getting lost in it to be fair.